# DELL iDRAC6 2.90 racadm syntax issue

Tags: dell

Включаем использование SD карты:
racadm config -g cfgRacVirtual -o cfgVirMediaKeyEnable 1

Инициализируем SD карту
racadm vflashsd initialize

Создаем раздел на SD карте (можно создать много, ограничимся одним):
racadm vflashpartition create -i 1 -o drive1 -t empty -e HDD -f fat32 -s 1024

До сих пор никаких проблем. Теперь надо подключить созданный раздел к хостовой ОС (Win 2008/Win 2012).

На стр 285-286 в "Integrated Dell Remote Access Controller 6 (iDRAC6) Version 1.95 User’s Guide" указан следующий синтаксис:
racadm config –g cfgvflashpartition –i 1 –o cfgvflashPartitionAccessType 1
racadm config –g cfgvflashpartition –i 1 –o cfgvflashPartitionAttachState 1
Но при его использовании выдается ошибка "ERROR: The syntax of the command specified is not correct."

Синтаксис от iDRAC 7/8 
racadm set iDRAC.vflashpartition.1.AccessType 0
racadm set iDRAC.vflashpartition.1.AttachState 1
тоже не работает.

Через WEB-интерфейс раздел подключается, все ОК.

Руководства для версий прошивки 2.xx не существует, последнее для 1.95. Откатываться на 1.95 не вариант.

Того, предположительно в версиях прошивки 2.xx был изменен синтаксис команд и эти изменения нигде не задокументированы.

Если кто-нибудь сталкивался, подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось банально.
Команды брались копи-пастом из оригинальных инструкций DELL. В этих инструкциях стоит неверный символ "-". Визуально он неотличим от правильного "-", но код символа отличается.

После исправления всех "-" команды вида
racadm config –g cfgvflashpartition –i 1 –o cfgvflashPartitionAccessType 1
заработали.

Извиняюсь у прочитавших за потраченное время..